# Page Curl effect in andengine

Tags: android, andengine, page-curl

i am using andengine. i have created different Scenes on which i am showing different images. I wanted to add page curl effect for each scene. How will i able to do that? or Is it possible to add page curl effect for different scenes ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at dis:

[android_page_curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/)